# Find pairs of numbers that add to a certain value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a function match that takes in a list of numbers and a target number and I want to write a function that finds within the array two numbers that add to that target.

Here is my approach:

```py
>>> def match(values, target=3):
...     for i in values:
...             for j in values:
...                     if j != i:
...                             if i + j == target:
...                                     return print(f'{i} and {j}')
...                             return print('no matching pair')
```

Is this solution valiant? Can it be improved?

Comment: I believe it's a question for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: why @jweyrich ?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would result in O(NlogN) solution.

1. You sort the list, this will cost you O(NlogN)
2. Once the list is sorted you get two indices, the former points to the first element, the latter -- to the latest element and you check to see if the sum of the elements matches whatever is your target. If the sum is above the target, you move the upper index down, if the sum is below the target -- you move the lower index up. Finish when the upper index is equal to the lower index. This operation is linear and can be done in O(N) time.

All in all, you have O(NlogN) for the sorting and O(N) for the indexing, bringing the complexity of the whole  solution to O(NlogN).

Answer (score 0):

There is room for improvement. Right now, you have a nested loop. Also, you do not `return` when you use `print`.

As you iterate over `values`, you are getting the following:

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
target = 3

first_value = 1
difference: 3 - 1 = 2
```

We can see that in order for 1 to add up to 3, a 2 is required. Rather than iterating over the `values`, we can simply ask `2 in values`.

```
def match(values, target):
    values = set(values)
    for value in values:
        summand = target - value
        if summand in values:
           break
    else:
        print('No matching pair')
    print(f'{value} and {summand}')
```

Edit: Converted values to a `set` since it has handles `in` quicker than if it were looking it up in a `list`. If you require the indices of these pairs, such as in the LeetCode problem you should not convert it to a `set`, since you will lose the order. You should also use `enumerate` in the for-loop to get the indices.

Edit: `summand == value` edge case

```
def match(values, target):
    for i, value in enumerate(values):
        summand = target - value
        if summand in values[i + 1:]:
           break
    else:
        print('No matching pair')
        return
    print(f'{value} and {summand}')
```

Comment: `summand in values` is a loop in a disguise, your solution is the same O(N^2) -- not much improvement here.

Comment: It outputs `1 and 3`, so it did. As a side note, this is not the most efficient method. The optimized version is using a dictionary.

Comment: mistyped, should be "try target `2` with the values `[1, 2, 3]` -- I bet your algorithm will find a non-existing pair"

Comment: It finds a pair, but I forgot about and edge case. Were `summand == value`. To fix that you just have to remove the `set`, since it is not subscriptable. You would also have to keep track of the index with `enumerate`, and do the following `summand in values[i + 1:]`.